# Solve $\cos \pi z = 0$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

$\cos \pi z = 0$,
so $\cos \pi x \cosh \pi y - i \sin \pi x \sinh \pi y = 0$,
$\cosh \pi y$ never be $0$, so $\cos \pi x = 0, \pi x=\pm \pi/2+2k\pi, x = \pm1/2+2k.$
 Is this the right way to do?

Comment: "so cosπx coshπy-i sinπx sinhπy= 0"

come on, some order in what you are writing, please.

Comment: Not really! You just analyzed one of the two terms of the sum.

Answer (score 6):

Why complicate things? By *definition*, $2\cos(z)=\mathrm e^{\mathrm iz}+\mathrm e^{-\mathrm iz}$ hence you are solving $$\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\pi z}+\mathrm e^{-\mathrm i\pi z}=0.$$ This equation is equivalent (*why?*) to  $\mathrm e^{2\mathrm i\pi z}+1=0$, which is equivalent (*why?*) to the equation $\mathrm e^{2\mathrm i\pi z}=\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\pi}$, which is equivalent (*why?*) to $2\mathrm i\pi z-\mathrm i\pi$ being in the set $U=\{u\in\mathbb C\mid \mathrm e^u=1\}$. Now, what do you know about $U$?